# how to stop repeat initialisation when using dynamicComponentContainer

Tags: angular, typescript, initialization, components, dynamically-generated

I've got a layout that loop through a list of components and loads me the component from the list.
To achieve this I have used dynamic-component, as I need to have a dynamic way to inject a component that is defined from an object.

If I click on a component that was loaded dynamically it runs the dynamic component 2,3,4 times.  I can't understand why after an even in the child component I get my components re-intialised. Is there a way to stop this or how should than inject dynamically the components.

This is the only way i have found to inject component dynamically and be able to pass data to the child as **ngComponentOutlet** that is currently in angular 4 does not let you pass and retrieve data from the created and injected child component.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vslspJ?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>

      <buttons (passdata)="getthis($event)" ></buttons>

      <button (click)="loadDogs()">Load Dogs</button>
      <hr />


      <div *ngFor="let comp of componentlist">

        <dynamic-component [componentData]="configureWidget(comp)"></dynamic-component>
      </div>
      <hr />


    </div>
  `,
})



export class AppComponent {


  componentlist:any = [
      { name: 'dogs', component: dogsComponent, inputName: 'colordata',   inputvalue: 'zzz' },
      { name: 'cats', component: catsComponent, inputName: 'showNum',  inputvalue: 'zzz' }
    ]

  configureWidget(widget){
    console.log(widget)

  if(widget.name == 'dogs'){
        return  this.componentData = {
                  component: widget.component,
                  inputs: {
                   showNum : 'ddddd',

                  }
                };
  }  
  if(widget.name == 'cats'){
        return  this.componentData = {
                  component: widget.component,
                  inputs: {
                   colordata : 'ddddd',

                  }
                };
  }      

  }
```

Comment: Your code is too confusing.  @Input() set componentData. Whenever you set componentData, you create a new component and as I see you set the componentData several times. I suggest you to remove setter method. Use interfaces instead of using something like this: componentData(data: {component: any, inputs: any })

Comment: @Omeralper, can you elaborate more on that? What you mean Use interfaces instead ?

Comment: It was just a suggestion for code readability. 
componentData(data: CustomType)
interface CustomType {component: any, inputs: any };

Comment: what about the initialisation?  that it keeps doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `AppComponent` and with how you pass the `componentData` to dynamic component. Angular's change detection knows about `variable` if they have changed or not but it can't tell that if you use a function in your template.

So don't use a function to pass processed data, otherwise changeDetection would call the function, process the data again and pass it, which will call your `setter` function in `dynamic-component` and initialize again.

[**Fixed Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7KFZeasYqKJlsZ7BaUUc?p=preview)

**Code:**

```
configuredWidgets = {};

  constructor(){
    this.componentlist.forEach(comp => {
      console.log(comp)

      if(comp.name == 'dogs'){
            this.configuredWidgets['dogs'] = {
                      component: comp.component,
                      inputs: {
                       showNum : 'ddddd',

                      }
                    };
      }  
      if(comp.name == 'cats'){
            this.configuredWidgets['cats'] = {
                      component: comp.component,
                      inputs: {
                       colordata : 'ddddd',

                      }
                    };
      }      

    })
  }
```